# can't get my markers to load

Tags: html, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from 'react-google-maps';

// const googleMapURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.27&libraries=places,geometry&key=AIzaSyASIGvujxniBb3bX8ZwMHjHbM13Ah6q9X';
const Map = props => (
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={16}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.6219853, lng: -73.94007739999999 }}
  >
    {
      props.displayed.forEach(device => device.locations.map((location, i) => (
        <Marker
          key={i}
          postion={{ lat: location.latitude, lng: location.longitude }}
          label={device.deviceName}
        />
      )))
    }
  </GoogleMap>

);
export default withGoogleMap(Map);
```

I can't get my markers to display the map renders fine the data being passed in is correct I have console logged it I am getting no errors in web pack or the console

[image]

Comment: You have a typo, too: `postion` should probably be `position`.

Comment: thanks changed it but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you return from within a forEach loop, the return value is undefined.  You actually need to return a list of Markers for react to render them, so switch that forEach to a map, and everything should work.

It's easy to test this out yourself:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
a.forEach(b => b); // returns undefined
a.map(b => b); // returns [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: the =>() is return shorthand

Comment: Yes, the map inside the forEach is returning, but even when you return from inside a forEach loop, it has an undefined return value.  Change the forEach to a map and it should work.